# try to printf a &a_variable

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I am new student in c language and I just come up with this. I code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
       int i=100;
       printf("Helloo is: %d\n", i);  
    }
```

and the output is: `Helloo is: 100` Till here is all great! If i change the code to this

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
       int i=100;
       printf("Helloo is: %d\n", &i);  // the &i is the change
    }
```

when i compile it, i get a warning: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat].` 
Ok, i get the message of the compiler, but i am curious so i run the program anyway and i get this output: `Helloo is: -1078455636` and if i run again the program i get a different output! So:

- all these numbers what are they? the memory addresses of the variable i?
- Why everytime i run the program i get a different output?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is basically "what is a pointer" and it's answered in every single tutorial and every college course on C.

Comment: Firstly as i said now i am learning c. Secondly, I am in the first chapters of the book and i dont know what are pointers. I just put & because i saw it in the function scanf("%d", &variable); and i said to try it in the printf also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("Helloo is: %d\n", &i);  // the &i is the change
```

This is Undefined behaviour

You need to specify correct format specifier.

To print address you need to use `%p` and  The standard says %p takes void * , so do cast.

```
printf("Helloo is: %p\n", (void *) &i);
```

Comment: thank you @Gangadhar! My goal wasn't to print the address of the variable but it was nice information you get me ;) One more question! i have a difficulty to understand what is `(void *)`

Comment: should i learn as it is? that %p needs this (void *) to work?

Comment: Knowing thing which is unknown is good, rather than following it blindly.`void *` is generic pointer. [See this](http://www.c4learn.com/void-pointers-in-c-programming.html)

Answer (score 1):

> all these numbers what are they? the memory addresses of the variable `i`?

They are a form of re-interpretation of `i`'s address as an integer - an undefined behavior: passing an address in place of an integer is not allowed.

> Why every time i run the program i get a different output?

The address of your variable changes all the time, so the code that re-interprets the address as an integer gets different data all the time.

If you want to print the address properly, use `%p` format specifier, and cast the address to `void*`:

```
printf("Hello is: %p\n", (void*)&i);
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the address-of operator, `&i` is a pointer to `int`. The value of `&i` changes because the address of the variable `i` is different every time you run the program.

Also, to print pointer address, use `%p` with `void *` type:

```
int i=100;
printf("Helloo is: %d\p\n", (void *)&i);
```

Comment: thank you @Yu Hao! My goal wasn't though to print the address of the variable but it was nice information you get me ;)  i have a difficulty to understand what is (void *). Should i learn as it is? that %p needs this (void *) to work?

Comment: @Nat95 `void *` is the generic pointer, and yes, `%p` needs to work with `void *`. I think you need to learn more about pointers generally first. You'll learn about `void *` there.